# android MapView always causes an OutOfMemoryError in nested elements

Tags: android, android-mapview, out-of-memory

I am trying to create a MapView (currently without any overlays) inside some nested elements.
It is basically something like `ScrollView -> RelativeLayout -> RelativeLayout -> MapView`

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="420px"
android:layout_height="300px"
android:clickable="false"
android:apiKey="key"/>
```

Seems fine for me. There is nothing more that I do with it on startup but it always causes the following:

```
04-04 13:38:33.910: WARN/dalvikvm(13628): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.Map.resize(Map.java:1368)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.Map.resize(Map.java:1337)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onMeasure(MapView.java:590)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1072)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:296)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-04 13:38:33.996: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13628):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 13:38:34.027: WARN/ActivityManager(6000):   Force finishing activity package/.home
04-04 13:38:34.527: WARN/ActivityManager(6000): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{405336d0 package/.home}
```

Do you have any idea why this is and what I can do to get rid of it? I can't take it out of that view as it is the place where I need it.

Thank you!

Comment: Is that everything you can see about this exception in the log cat? Seems a little bit short for a whole exception stack trace. Another thing is, I think it's a little bit weird to put a MapView into a ScrollView as you might get into trouble when someone wants to scroll within the map.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I now pasted the whole stacktrace. Thought that is mostly unnecessary stuff. Unfortunately I have to put the MapView into the ScrollView. I hope (when the MapView gets shown) I can modify it that it takes the scrolling gesture when the user does it on the view, otherwise the ScrollView should scroll.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found out something quite simple.

Just place the MapView inside a FrameLayout. Let the FramgeLayout be wrap_content | wrap_content and everything is fine :)

This one fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <view android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="90dip" class="com.google.android.maps.MapView"
                android:apiKey="@string/API_KEY" android:clickable="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.resize(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onMeasure(MapView.java:554)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:989)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:286)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:805)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

An here the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <view android:layout_width="100dip" android:layout_height="90dip" class="com.google.android.maps.MapView"
                    android:apiKey="@string/API_KEY" android:clickable="true" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Greetings,
Marco

Comment: I want to upvote your response everytime when i stuck on this problem, find this post and you save my day! But i just cant do it. Only once, sorry :)

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem as well, it occurs when you try to specify the exact dimensions of a mapview. Set one of the dimensions to fill_parent or wrap_content and let the other be whatever dimension you want. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately that does not work for me. I am still getting the OutOfMemoryError. The remaining layout takes around 8 MB, maybe that is simply too much for a MapView.

Comment: Possibly - I'm not too sure. If you strip out the layout leaving just the mapview does it work with the dimensions you gave it?

Comment: Thank you again! My mistake has to be somewhere else. I stripped my layout down by some expensive objects (which I need, but I removed them for testing) but I am still getting the Error altough I have 32 MiB max heap size on my device. I don't think I am exceeding it. Maybe MapView has some problems with often nested views :(

Comment: One last option: Try defining one dimension of the immediate parent of the mapview as whatever dip and the other as fill parent. Set both dimension of the mapview itself to fill_parent

Comment: Thanks again! I tried that but unfortunately it does not make a difference.

Comment: There seems to be a Memoryleak in the mapview implemenation: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=mapview%20memory&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=26546 

Star the issue if you think that causes your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see where you are getting an OutOfMemoryError? I do see this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
```

Which says you can only create a MapView inside a class that extends MapActivity, and it implies that you do not do this?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to change my activity back to MapActivity. Now I pasted in the correct code with the OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the following thread:

[Issue 2181:Memory leak in system when using MapView](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2181)

Seems like this is something internal in MapActivity. The thread is alive for over two years now and it was not reported as fixed...

Edit: tried the solution described there and it led me to a similar solution:

```
try {
        Field mConfigField = MapActivity.class.getDeclaredField("mConfig");
        mConfigField.setAccessible(true);

        Object mConfig = mConfigField.get(this);
        if (null != mConfig)
        {
            Field mConfigContextField = mConfig.getClass().getDeclaredField("context");
            mConfigContextField.setAccessible(true);

            mConfigContextField.set(mConfig, null);

            mConfigField.set(this, null);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Do error handling
    }
```

Comment: The leak is a legitimate problem but in this case it's an instantaneous OOM — different bug.

Answer (score 2):

steemcb is correct, but unfortunately [there is also a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11183) in `MapView` that causes this to happen *even if your layout is good.* I got the exact same stack trace as yours. It is a fragile component and small changes in layout type will cause it to break unexpectedly, especially if it's wrapped in a `ScrollLayout`.

It hasn't yet been addressed by anyone from the Android project.

Answer (score 1):

Actually its caused by placing the MapView in a Scrollview.  See [android MapView always causes an OutOfMemoryError in nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460650/android-mapview-always-causes-an-outofmemoryerror-in-nested-elements/6535957#6535957) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is caused by Scrollview creating a buffer to contain the view at each possible position of the scrollbar to enable fast and smooth scrolling.  Since a MapView is pretty large when the tiles are loaded during the measure phase then the resulting buffer created by ScrollView can be huge (around 128 M).  Unless you set your emulator to have more than 256 M of ram and heap space, it will fail with an out of memory error.  You could set your emulator to have 512M of ram and heap space but your app would crash on any device that has less than 512M of ram or insufficient heap space.  The best thing to do is to remove the MapView from the ScrollView.