# android GoogleMaps memory leaks (?)

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks

I'm working on a project dealing with map activities. 
I was running a testing app consisting of a single activity, MaptestActivity, that extends MapActivity and does nothing else. I rotated the device more than ten times and I analyzed the heap dump with MAT. I noticed the existence of two instances of the main activity hanging around (a leak?). I re-tested the app with the same activity extending only Activity: the dump showed only one instance being kept by the system, the current one.
I'm attaching the screenshots of both cases. I'm not much into MAT, maybe I'm just misunderstanding the reults and everything works fine. Could you please shed some light on it?

[With memory leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDZZY.png)

[Without memory leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y616C.png)

Comment: Not yet, I'm working on it (using reflection). I'll post the solution as soon as I (hopefully) find one!

Answer (score 1):

If you still have two activities in memory after rotating the device then you do have a memory leak.  You can use MAT to see what is preventing that activity from being garbage collected by using the Histogram.  Search on the class name to find it.  Then right click on it and select list objects/with incoming references.  That will list each occurrence of this object in memory.  Right click on one of these objects and select Path to GC roots/exclude weak references.  Now you should be able to see a hierarchy of objects, of which something is not getting cleaned up completely after the activity's onDestroy has finished.  Things like hard references to a static context will cause this.  To resolve some of our memory issues we've had to do things like use weakReferences where appropriate, and clean things up in onDestroy (like setting listeners to null).

Normally if your activities are not holding onto large objects like bitmaps you can "get away" with memory leaks since it would mean lots of app usage before you exceed the device's application heap size.  But if say all of your activities hold onto a large bitmap, then leaking activities become much more of a big deal.

This is a good video: [Memory Management for Android Apps](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=_CruQY55HOk)
And a good article: [Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: Thanks Scott. That's what I did. Here follows a screenshot of what's holding homeActivity: [link](http://postimage.org/image/7vauzrru9/). It seems like a google maps' object keeping a reference to it. As I previously said, homeActivity extends MapActivity and does nothing else (it doesn't event load a map).

Comment: See if you can call something to clear out the object being held onto in onDestroy.  If no method is available and there's no public variable you can't set to null that will clear it out, you can use reflection to access the private variable in question to null it out.  It looks like this is a known problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460650/android-mapview-always-causes-an-outofmemoryerror-in-nested-elements

Answer (score -1):

add the below line in for your activity in your manifeast file

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Comment: True, this will prevent the activity from being recreated. Sounds like a work-around, though.