# Is a ViewSwitcher and MapView combinaison bound to throw an OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, out-of-memory

I have in my Android application a layout with a `MapView` in a `ViewSwitcher` (which is it self in a `RelativeLayout` and takes not the entire screen).

My problem is that tapping the item is very slow, and after a few taps it triggers a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` (both on device and emulator).

```
07-19 15:39:29.839: E/dalvikvm-heap(14832): 86400-byte external allocation too large for this process.
07-19 15:39:29.839: E/GraphicsJNI(14832): VM won't let us allocate 86400 bytes
07-19 15:39:29.889: I/dalvikvm-heap(14832): Clamp target GC heap from 32.934MB to 32.000MB
07-19 15:39:29.889: D/dalvikvm(14832): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 29% free 8447K/11847K, external 20846K/21207K, paused 47ms
07-19 15:39:29.889: D/skia(14832): --- decoder->decode returned false
07-19 15:39:29.889: D/AndroidRuntime(14832): Shutting down VM
07-19 15:39:29.889: W/dalvikvm(14832): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:504)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:370)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:715)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:675)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at mypackage.widgets.LocalisationArrayAdapter.getView(LocalisationArrayAdapter.java:92)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1498)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1220)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1131)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8462)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3231)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:254)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8462)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8462)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3231)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:254)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8462)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:535)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:313)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8462)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3231)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:254)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8462)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:861)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1882)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
07-19 15:39:29.889: E/AndroidRuntime(14832):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So my question is : what really causes this error?

1. Is this the not full-screen `MapView` ?

   I followed this post's solution: [android MapView always causes an OutOfMemoryError in nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460650/android-mapview-always-causes-an-outofmemoryerror-in-nested-elements) but it did not do anything.
2. Is it that because of the `ViewSwitcher` both the `MapView` and its other child (a `ListView`) are in memory?

   If so, how can I make android redraw each view on `showNext()`?

When I had two different activities instead of the `ViewSwitcher`, and when the `MapView` took the entire layout it worked fine, so what makes it wrong and how can I change that?

Comment: hey did you ever resolve this?

Comment: No I did not have time to solve it before I was off the project.