# form with MapView with input in a ScrollView doesn't display anything

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-scrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android MapView always causes an OutOfMemoryError in nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460650/android-mapview-always-causes-an-outofmemoryerror-in-nested-elements)

sorry for asking but since yesterday i do not find the solution : i'm a beginner and i want to make a form with some inputs, some buttons and a mapView. There is many things then i had put a ScrollView. But it doesn't work anymore and i don't find why..

Here is my file.java

```
public class Application extends MapActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;}
}
```

And here is my long layout.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateEvenementTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Date Evenement" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/typeEvenementTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
        android:text="Type Evenement" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dateEntree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dateEvenementTextView"
        android:text="05/09/2012"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:maxLength="10" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/listeDeChoix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/typeEvenementTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/typeEvenementTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adresseTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dateEntree"
        android:text="Adresse" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/adresse_entree"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adresseTextView"
        android:text="10 rue de rivoli" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/codePostalTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/adresse_entree"
        android:text="Code postal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/codePostal_entree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/codePostalTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="75001"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/villeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/codePostal_entree"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Ville" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ville_entree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/villeTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/villeTextView"
        android:text="Paris"/>

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/codePostal_entree"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:apiKey="MapKey"
    />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mapview"
        android:text="Image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bouton_choisir_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageTextView"
        android:text="Selectionner une image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_choisie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bouton_choisir_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_choisie"
        android:text="Description" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/description_multilignes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descriptionTextView"
        android:text="Texte prétapé pour éviter de le retapé à chaque fois"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:minLines="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bouton_valider_formulaire"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/description_multilignes"
        android:text="Valider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In advance, thank you for answer(s)

**EDIT** : This is my graphical layout (shown by eclipse in the tab graphical layout. As you can see, every thing is present and despite the warnings (because i have not set android:text="@string/str") it work when i don't set `ScrollView`

As spam prevention i'm not allowed to post image in StackoverFlow then this is a link toward another site (postimage dot org)
http://postimage.org/image/dm9rlnnc1/

Comment: Can you post a picture what it looks like? Is everything there but the MapView?

Comment: @Ridcully Thanks again; i have posted the screen view using Uploadimage dot org, link is above and below http://postimage.org/image/dm9rlnnc1/

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your MapView some weight using `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I have tried but still doesn't work

Thx

Comment: Ok the problem is fixed ! i'm so sorry because the solution was already given :/ 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460650/android-mapview-always-causes-an-outofmemoryerror-in-nested-elements

Just need to set a `FrameLayout` and nest the mapview in this FrameLayout

Thanks Ridcully for your help